# Tuning SVM parameters using svm.tune e1071 package

Tags: r, svm, libsvm

I am trying to perform classification using Support Vector Machines in R using e1071 package. Using the following code, and specifying the cost and gamma parameters, I could train the models successfully.

```
svm_models <- lapply(training_data,
                function(data)
                {
                  svm(label~., data=data,
                      method="C-classification", kernel="radial",
                      cost=10, gamma=0.1)
                })
```

But If I perform paramter tuning within the above function as the following code,

```
svmmodels <- lapply(trainingdata,
                function(data)
                {
                  params <- tune.svm(label~., data=data,
                                    gamma=10^(-6:-2), cost=10^(1:2))
                  svm(label~., data=data,
                      method="C-classification", kernel="radial",
                      cost=params$best.parameter[[2]], gamma=params$best.parameter[[1]])
                })
```

then I get the following error:

> Error in predict.svm(ret, xhold, decision.values = TRUE) (from #4) :
> Model is empty!

What could be the possible cause of this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to `?tune`, it should be `best.parameters`, not `best.parameter`.  Try adding the 's' at the end of both instances in your code, and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to say much definitive with no data for testing, (or even a description of the data). However, it is possible to say that your calling `svm` after `tune.svm` is not in keeping with the example in the `e1071::tune` help page. Furthermore the formal parameter that the "cost" and "price" parmeters should be given as list elements is "range". You should not need to run svm on the output.